# Question about tensor product of modules and ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Trying to prove some properties of tensor product with a given module, I came up with questions some of them I can't prove. Maybe it is also because Im not very used to work with tensor products and I think they can be tricky.

So let $A$ be a ring and let $M$ be an $A$-module. Let $I,J$ be any ideals of $A$. Now, is it true

$$JI \otimes_A M \subset J(I \otimes_A M)$$

maybe the above is an equality but I only need that...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a canonical surjective homomorphism $JI \otimes_A M \to J(I \otimes_A M)$. It is injective when $M$ is flat (but not in general).

Comment: Ok, thank you, I asked a more concrete question here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585597/tensor-product-artin-rees-lemma-and-krull-intersection-theorem since that doesnt solve my problem.